# How do you get the sidebar to fill up the space?

Tags: javascript, css

Using [this](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) technique for sticky footers and give [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AfwzD/2/) example.

```
* { margin:0; }
html, body { height:100%; }
#wrap { 
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto !important;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 0 -47px;
}
#side { float:left; background:#ccc; width:100px; overflow:hidden; }
#body { float:left; background:#aaa; width:300px; }
#foot, .push { height:47px; }
#foot { background:#eee; }
```

How do you make it so that the sidebar and/or the content box fills up the space between the header and footer?

I've tried setting the height to 100%, but it (not surprisingly) doesn't seem to take. And I can't set a fixed height since it would still break on bigger screens.

Anyone want to shed some light on this?

EDIT:
The answer selected on for this question doesn't work for designs with semi-transparent footers. Show here: http://jsfiddle.net/AfwzD/23/

As such, I would like to add this to the question then. How do you make it work for this type of design?

Comment: Check out Faux Columns for a quick and easy hack: http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns Basically, you're creating a background in the parent div that makes the columns appear to extend to the full height of the tallest div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little bit tricky. The only one way to do it which I found is setting huge padding-bottom and opposite margin to compensate it. Plus you have to give `#wrap` `overflow: hidden`:

```
#body {
    ...
    padding: 80px 20px 1050px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AfwzD/21/

Comment: I've tried this on the actual project and it doesn't work. Unfortunately, I can't show the actual code to that. But this has pointed me in the right direction, as I didn't actually think of trying this technique on fiddle. I guess it's my stylesheet that's causing problems. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: Probably, because I use this technique on my own project and it works fine even in IE.

Comment: Oh and it should be mentioned, this won't work for footers that are semi-transparent design-wise. As shown on this example: http://jsfiddle.net/AfwzD/23/. Don't want to ask another question so I will just edit this one.

Comment: Yes, this way will not work. But why do you need semitransparent footer? You can try to nest several divs in the footed, make topmost semitransparent and under it place the one with needed background color.

Comment: What I'm working on involves a full screen image background. So yeah, basically, it's because of the design.

Comment: You can duplicate background image for footer inner div (`#back`) and adjust background-position. Then you place another div over it (`#cont`) and give it opacity. `<div id="foot"><div class="back"></div><div class="cont">Some footer content</div></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do it through javascript. Somewhat like this.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function ()
{
    /*var nContentHeight = window.innerHeight - headerHeight - footerHeight;*/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your floating elements so they are placed back in the flow of the page.

**HTML**

```
<div id="side">...</div>
<div id="body">...</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clear { clear:both; }
```